# Pear DB Error: extension not found

Tags: php, mysql, pear

I am still new to php and linux but i try to give you all information I know.
We got a PHP web application using pear and smarty. It's runing on PHP 4 on a Linux system and with XAMP and PHP5 on my PC. I am trying to move the application on a new server with PHP7 and updated PEAR and all extensions (it's the same version as on XAMP), but all I get is: DB Error: extension not found. 
I tried to find a solution but wasn't able to find anything which could help me.
The database we are using is a normal mysql database.
I'm not sure if there is still a path missing or what went wrong.

Maybe someone of you got a clue what the problem could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your very old PHP4 code is using the `mysql_` database extension?

If so that extension has been deprecated for years and was completely removed from PHP7. You wont be able to move that code to any version of PHP higher than PHP5.6 and even trying to do that you will almost definitely come across lots of other incompatibilities

I suggest you read http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php in the menu on this page there is a section on migrating from all sorts of versions of PHP.

You will have to work out how far up the migration levels your code will actually move without major amendments. I would guess, not very far!

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer and the idea to migrate step by step and not directly to PHP7. I already read about migration but had no clue where to start and hoped there was an easier way to do that but this would be the best.

Comment: Just to give a short update: PHP 5.6 and below is working fine so the incompatibility is only at PHP 7.

Comment: Working now. I didn't noticed that PEAR gets the information whether to use mysql or mysqli from the defined dns.